# When should I move up from Freeroll MTT's?

Tags: texas-hold-em, tournament, mtt

Theoretically, if I have been playing Free rollers for a month, and played in 250 of them, winning 3 and coming into the money in 50, how many more should I play before I move up to the next stake level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're moving up in limits, based mostly on your skill and `bankroll`.
This is because tournaments have a degree of `variance` and want to have enough bankroll to survive during *downswings*, while you're gaining enough to increase you bankroll.

But for `Freerolls`, there's no danger of losing a bankroll, you can only win money. Therefore, your only consideration of moving up is mostly your `skill`.

About the `when to move up`, you have to realize how good you're in your current stakes. Use a tracker, for example [FPDB](http://fpdb.wikidot.com) or [Pokertracker](https://www.pokertracker.com). The "problem" here is that you can't have a [ROI](http://www.thepokerbank.com/strategy/tournament/roi/), since you're not really investing anything.

In real money tournaments, it requires a good ROI and a good sample of tournaments (eg. 500 or 1000+) to consider moving up. Here, it takes a rough estimation.

Do you win enough, based on the *time spent*? If yes, move up or multi-table in current stakes.